# python search for tag using bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 

url = ""
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

I'm trying to save the value 15.720 from a website into a variable using python 3. Currently I have saved the html into the soup variable.

How do I search for the line below and save the number 15.720 into a variable?

```
<td class="myclass" rowspan="2">lor be: <strong>15.720</strong></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `soup.find("td", class_="myclass").strong.text`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<td class="myclass" rowspan="2">lor be: <strong>15.720</strong></td>', "html.parser")
print(soup.find("td", class_="myclass").strong.text)
```

**Output:**

```
15.720
```